# How to get current monthly interval from given date till today in PHP?

Tags: php

For example the starting  date is 5th January 2017 and today is 7th April 2017. So 5th Jan to 5th Feb interval 1, 5th Feb to 5th march interval 2, 5th march to 5th April interval 3. 5th April till 5th may interval 4.

So if today is 7th April result should return interval 4.

Comment: i just answer my question. i think till yet testing. seems working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function currrent_monthly_interval($from_date)
{
    $interval = date_diff(date_create($from_date), date_create(date('Y-m-d')));

    return intval($interval->format('%m')) + 1 ;
}
```

Comment: I found solution  i believe . Seems like working fine